# 2D C# Collecting Item For Acceleration Unity

Tags: c#, 2d, transformation

I have an issue regarding acceleration for Unity in C#, I'm trying to have my player collect an item and gain speed from it. Now, I have this working, but I need it to be a gradual acceleration, I don't want my player to just instantly jump to the maximum speed like he is now.

Here is how far I've got, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not. Any help?

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {

            if (other.tag == "speedBoost") {

            transform.position += Vector3.right * acceleration * Time.deltaTime;

            if (acceleration < horizontalSpeed) {
            acceleration += 1;
        }
                    //transform.position += Vector3.right * horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                    Destroy (other.gameObject); 
            }
    }
```

I appreciate any help you can give, thanks!

Comment: You will need to control it in an Update method not a detection method. You will use the detection method to determine when you should start speeding up.

Comment: Alright, how might one go about achieving that, specifically?

Comment: Rather than giving you the answer, I'll point you in the right direction. If I were to implement something like this, I would use http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html You'll need to rearrange and redesign your implementation of this. I would suggest having a boolean value that is used to determine when to increase the acceleration. If you think about it, all you are doing is checking to see if something is true, and if it is then interpolate between your normal acceleration to your max acceleration over time. Understand?

Comment: Alright thanks, I've tried for a couple of hours to work that out but it's not coming together for me yet. If you could offer a few more clues that might help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mathf.Lerp. Mathf.Lerp takes in 'From', 'To' and 'T' parameters. It interpolates your value From to To over T. The T parameter should be a value between 0 and 1. 0 is equal to your From value and 1 is equal to your To value.

For example:

**From** = 1

**To** = 2

**Difference** = **To** - **From** = 1

So if T were equal to 0.5, the returned value would be 1.5

I'm not entirely sure what your exact plans for this idea are or how it will tie into your game, but I have constructed a basic script for you to read over and understand what is happening.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PowerUpTest : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float minSpeed = 1.0f;   //Minimum powerup speed 'From'
    public float maxSpeed = 10.0f;  //Maximum powerup speed 'To'
    public float incrementRate = 0.1f;  //The rate you want the speed to change
    public string powerUpName = "SpeedBoost";   //The tag of the powerup gameobject

    private bool executePowerUp = false;  //Checks whether to execute the powerup 
    private float currentSpeed; //The current speed of your powerup boost value
    private float lerpTime;  //The lerp time 'T'

    void Start () 
    {
        currentSpeed = minSpeed; //Set current speed to equal the minimum speed
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (executePowerUp) //If the executePowerUp bool is true
        {
            if (lerpTime <= 1) //If the lerp time has not reached the maximum value ('To')
            {
                lerpTime += Time.deltaTime * incrementRate; //Increase the lerp time by deltaTime multiplied by the rate
                currentSpeed = Mathf.Lerp (minSpeed, maxSpeed, lerpTime); //Set the current speed to the current lerped value
                print (currentSpeed); //print the current speed for you to see the change in the value
            }
            else //If the lerp time has exceeded the 'To' value
            {
                executePowerUp = false; //Turn execute powerup to false
                lerpTime = 0; //Reset the lerp time
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag (powerUpName)) //If the trigger object tag is equal to the powerup tag
        {
            executePowerUp = true; //Set execute power to true to initiate the lerp code
            Destroy (other.gameObject); //Remove the collided object
        }
    }
}
```

The code is fully commented. If you don't understand something, post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The first clear issue is this line:

```
transform.position += Vector3.right * acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
```

`transform.position` is in length units (it's value represents distances along the 3 world axes from the origin).

In this line of code you are adding a value with velocity units to a variable with length units. `acceleration` is length/time^2, `Time. deltaTime` is time, and `Vector3.right` is unitless (it's a direction). Multiplied together we get length/time which is velocity.

Perhaps the name of the `acceleration` variable is misleading and it's actually velocity. By any case, you have to make sure your units check out first. Then, to get the effect you want what you want to do is instead of adding values to the position of the object, add values to it's maximum speed (store this variable somewhere in a component).

Comment: Alright, thanks, yeah I get what you're saying, didn't know transform was a distance thing, I'm still not entirely sure how to translate the information you've provided into usable code, but I'll try some stuff.